# rspec Mongoid scope works in development not in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mongoid

I've got a scope I apply to a Mongoid object in rails that works great when in development, but not when running tests.  It actually doesn't work at all in tests.  This is an embedded document.

The parent:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  def self.with_appointments
    where(:appointments.not => { '$size' => 0 })
  end
  embeds_many :appointments, store_as: 'Appointments', class_name: 'Appointment'
end
```

The embedded child:

```
class Appointment
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :person
end
```

When I run tests against my model it returns Persons whether they have appointments or not.  If I run the same from my controller in development against the database it filters out people with empty appointments.

What am I missing?

Before asking me to change the database setup -

1. I don't have control over data structure
2. Assume I don't even have write access to the database

Comment: Can you add snippet of your test & development code? including setup

Comment: Is there something in particular you are interested in?  Test and development code plus all of the setup would definitely be a huge wall of code so maybe there's something more specific?

Comment: I would pause the test using Pry and inspect the database. Make sure that the records are actually persisted? Compare the records within each collection to see if they are the same as you're expecting. Some of the test source code would help.

Comment: @KevinMonk Yeah that's what's weird, using ByeBug I put in a debug but the test DB has nothing in it.  I'll see what I can do without getting too deep here.

Comment: @PWKad what do you want?

Comment: Maybe the following approach will enable you to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) without a wall of code: List the commands (like `rails new` and `rails generate <...>`) and manual edits needed to reproduce the behavior you experience.

Answer (score 0):

Check your GemFile, I'll bet Mongoid is set to run only in development:

Try switching this

```
gem 'mongoid', group: :development
```

to this

```
gem 'mongoid'
```